# Bundler and RVM for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have bundler do I still need rvm for Rails 3 applications in production?
I'm not pretend to have many ruby version running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need RVM if you are happy with Ruby version bundled with your production server OS.

However Linux distributions usually have old, not patched versions of Ruby. So I suggest to install RVM, this is quite easy to do, and install newest patched Ruby version.

Comment: thanks, in the past I used RVM because some conflicts between gems from Rails 2 and 3, but in this case I only want to use Rails 3 , and I think bundler makes a good job, isn't it?